# Heroku run rake db:seed Couldn't drop database error

Tags: postgresql, heroku, rake

Rails app that seeds fine locally won't seed on Heroku.

- It will do a successful `heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK_URL`
- It will do a successful `heroku run db:migrate`
- It will do a successful `heroku run rake db:migrate:status` (and all looks good)

The application runs, but won't seed.

It will NOT do a successful `db:seed`

The error is:

```
dbcuqurj68jdre already exists
Couldn't drop dbcuqurj68jdre : #<PG::Error: FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
```

Can't figure that one out, since I was able to do the full

```
heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK_URL
```

Comment: I know it's been a while since this bug. But do you remember what changes you made to the seed.rb file?

Answer (score 1):

Solved with an update to our seed.rb file. ... we were missing the faker gem.